# App Pool Accounts in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepointfoundation2010

How to change app pool account credentials for any web application in sharepoint 2010

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to following:

Central Admin – Security – Configure Service Account – General Security – Configure Managed Account

Then edit the managed account that corresponds to your application pool. You will have an option to change the password on the edit page.

You can also do the same with a Powershell command named: 
Set-SPManagedAccount.